# How to use JNAerator with multiple dynamic libraries under one header?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, cross-platform, jnaerator

I am using JNAerator to generate a single jar file I can include in a project, and I'd like to support the dynamic libraries for each operating system and arch all in this single jar.

In fiddling with JNAerator so far, I've been able to include a single dynamic library using a command like the following:

```
java -jar jnaerator.jar test.dll test.h [...] -mode StandaloneJar
```

However, this only packages `test.dll`, while I have dynamic libraries for multiple systems (`test_win32.dll`, `test_win64.dll`, `libtest_mac.dylib`, `libtest_linux_x86.so`, and `libtest_linux_amd64.so`) which I would like to all have packaged into and supported by one jar.

Is there any way to do this "all-in-one" approach with one run of JNAerator, or must I generate a different jar file for each platform?

Comment: Hi FThompson, when I created JAR of it, inside that how I can get the JNA filed to use that in my Java project? Were you able to get that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JNAerator has an `-arch` option designed just for that, although [the doc is currently terribly vague about it](https://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/wiki/CommandLineOptionsAndEnvironmentVariables):

```
java -jar jnaerator-0.12-shaded.jar \
  -arch win32 win32/test.dll \
  -arch win64 win64/test.dll \
  -arch darwin_universal mac/libtest.dylib \
  -arch linux_x86 linux_x86/libtest.so \
  -arch linux_x64 linux_amd64/libtest.so \
  test.h \
  -mode StandaloneJar \
  -jar test.jar
```

This will bundle the libraries under the format expected by [BridJ](https://code.google.com/p/bridj/) (see [its wiki page about embedded binaries](https://code.google.com/p/bridj/wiki/LibrariesLookup)):

`unzip -l test.jar` gives:

```
    ...
    0  04-09-15 22:45   lib/win32/test.dll
    0  04-09-15 22:45   lib/win64/test.dll
    0  04-09-15 22:45   lib/darwin_universal/libtest.dylib
    0  04-09-15 22:45   lib/linux_x86/libtest.so
    0  04-09-15 22:45   lib/linux_x64/libtest.so
```

The library names are currently expected to be exactly `lib<name>.(so|dylib)` or `<name>.dll` for every platform, although that could easily be fixed [if you ask](https://github.com/nativelibs4java/JNAerator/issues).

(note: I'm the author of BridJ & JNAerator)

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Look forward to some bounty reputation once I can (due to the two-day limit) as a thank you for both this answer and your great work on JNAerator and your other projects :)

Comment: Hi zOlive, when I created JAR of it, inside that how I can get the JNA filed to use that in my Java project?